# Is it possible to backup an iOS 7.1.2 device on OSX 10.12, 10.13, or 10.15?

Tags: macos, ios, itunes, backup, photos

I have an old iPhone 4 with iOS 7.1.2 that I want to backup and sync the photos off of.  I have a macOS 10.12, 10.13 and 10.15 device that I was hoping to backup to (if I have to I can try to dig up some older macbooks that might have an older version of OSX on them).  For some reason when I plug the iphone 4 in to any device then the iPhone doesn't show up in Finder or iTunes (tho it does draw power from the mac), so I'm not able to make a backup or import the photos.

I'm wondering why the iphone doesn't show up on any macOS device that I plug it in to, and what I need to do to make a backup and/or import the photos?

Comment: Is it possible your cable has a break in the data lines?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, any iPhone with an iOS lower than 13 cannot back up their photos onto a Mac through a USB connection. However, you could try using Google Drive and then accessing your drive on your laptop (although, I am not sure if google drive works for iOS 7).

Comment: With an older version of OSX it must be possible to backup thru USB, so I wonder what version of OSX I would need to do this (then hopefully I might have an old mac with that version of OSX).